# Закрывается клавиатура после нажатия инпута React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Есть компонент навигации, подключается в компоненте App

```
return (
            <>
                <MainState/>
            </>
```

Внутри него есть два компонента по которым происходит навигация

```
return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
            >
                {/*<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Auth} />*/}
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='AuthScreen'
                    component={Auth}
                    options={{
                        title:'Учетные записи',
                        headerStyle:{
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle:{
                           textAlign:'center',
                            width:screenWidth-35,
                           // backgroundColor:'yellow',
                            fontFamily:'Inter',
                            fontWeight:'400',
                            fontSize:16,
                            lineHeight:20
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='AuthLogin'
                    component={AuthLogin}
                    options={{
                        title:'Подключение уч. записи',
                        headerTitleStyle:{
                            textAlign:'center',
                            fontFamily:'Inter',
                            fontWeight:'400',
                            fontSize:16,
                            lineHeight:20
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        )
```

В компоненте AuthLogin есть ряд инпутов

```
const AuthLogin = () => {


    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput placeholder={'Логин'} style={[styles.inputText, styles.input, {marginTop: 16}]} autoCorrect={false}/>
                    <TextInput placeholder={'Пароль'} style={[styles.inputText, styles.input]} />
                    <TextInput placeholder={'IP адрес сервера'} style={[styles.inputText, styles.input]} keyboardType="numeric"/>
                    <TextInput placeholder={'Название учетной записи'} style={[styles.inputText, styles.input]}/>

                <Button style={styles.buttonForm}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Подключить</Text></Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default AuthLogin;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на инпут появляется клавиатура и через секунду исчезает

Я пытался вынести инпут в основной компонент App и все работало, а через навигацию нет

Такое поведение наблюдается при сборке npm run android и на реальном устройстве

В чем может быть причина? Спасибо

Comment: Удалось решить проблему? Ловлю тоже самое

Comment: Я понизил версию react-navigation, вроде помогло